# How to make a dropdown box & description box validate field?

Tags: php, validation, dokan

I'm using Dokan plugin for my website. I need to validate the dropdown box & description box of my website. I used some code to validate product name, price, item code it's working fine (check [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGRP0.png)). If you check screenshot 2 you will see when I do not select the values in the product categories dropdown it will show an error message (error & dropdown came from Dokan plugin). I need to make my dropdown like that. I added the location dropdown box by hard code in PHP. I cannot find a method to validate these dropdown & description box (check [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ephky.png)).

This is the code I use to validate my other fields, in child theme/funtion.php

```
 function dokan_can_add_product_validation_customized( $errors ) {
 $postdata = wp_unslash( $_POST );



$featured_image = absint( sanitize_text_field( $postdata['feat_image_id'] ) );
  $_regular_price = absint( sanitize_text_field( $postdata['_regular_price'] ) );
  $item_code= absint( sanitize_text_field( $postdata['item_code'] ) );

  
$phone_number= absint( sanitize_text_field( $postdata['phone_number'] ) );

  if ( empty( $featured_image ) && ! in_array( 'Please upload a product cover image' , $errors ) ) {
      $errors[] = 'Please upload a product cover image';
  }
  if ( empty( $_regular_price ) && ! in_array( 'Please insert product price' , $errors ) ) {
      $errors[] = 'Please insert product price';
  }
  if ( empty( $item_code) && ! in_array( 'Please insert item code' , $errors ) ) {
      $errors[] = 'Please insert item code';
  }

 if ( empty( $phone_number) && ! in_array( 'Please insert contact number' , $errors ) ) {
      $errors[] = 'Please insert contact number';
  }


  return $errors;
}
add_filter( 'dokan_can_add_product', 'dokan_can_add_product_validation_customized', 35, 1 );
add_filter( 'dokan_can_edit_product', 'dokan_can_add_product_validation_customized', 35, 1 );
function dokan_new_product_popup_validation_customized( $errors, $data ) {
  if ( ! $data['_regular_price'] ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'no-price', __( 'Please insert product price', 'dokan-lite' ) );
  }
  if ( ! $data['phone_number'] ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'no-price', __( 'Please insert Please insert contact number', 'dokan-lite' ) );
  }
 if ( ! $data['item_code'] ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'no-price', __( 'Please insert item code', 'dokan-lite' ) );
  }
 

  if ( ! $data['feat_image_id'] ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'no-image', __( 'Please select AT LEAST ONE Picture', 'dokan-lite' ) );
  }
}
add_filter( 'dokan_new_product_popup_args', 'dokan_new_product_popup_validation_customized', 35, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

i found a method to validate dropdown, here is the code

```
    if(isset($_REQUEST['plocation']) && $_REQUEST['plocation'] == '0') { 
 
$errors[] = 'Please select a location'; 
}
```